# Retrieving SecurityContext object by Dependency Injection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to protect my REST Apis.

I am able to retrieve the injected Principal object in my RestController:

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(Principal user) {
user.getName();
```

But unfortunately, the Principal object has no **getAuthorities()** method which I need to read out the user's role.

That's why I am using the static method to get the desired information what I need :

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser() {
//how to get the SecurityContext by DI ?
Authentication user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Is there any easy solution to get the current **SecurityContext** object by Dependency injection ?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal

Answer (score 0):

Please try following way:

```
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
Authentication getAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
    return authentication;
}
```

It's supported by [`ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.html), `Authentication` is child class of `Principal`

```
  if (Principal.class.isAssignableFrom(paramType)) {
      return request.getUserPrincipal();
  }
```